# Wpf MVVM - Binding not applied in ViewModel before View is showing (Async / await)

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I have a small error, when I try to bind a ObservableCollection in the ViewModel. The problem is that it connects to a web api to get the list, but for some reason, it not quick enough.

I think it has something to do with async / await where it's not waiting for the list to get its data before the view is loaded.

**Code:**

```
public ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel> AvailableRooms { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel> List { get; set; }
```

The AvailableRooms is the correct list, and the List is just for testing.

```
public RoomsViewModel(IGetAvailableRoomsService getAvailableRoomsService)
{
    //Injection
    _getAvailableRoomsService = getAvailableRoomsService;

    //Initialize
    AvailableRooms = new ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel>();

    //Get all rooms
    GetAvailableRooms();

    List = new ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel>();

    List.Add(new AvailableRoomModel { Id = 1, RoomNumber = "101", Occupied = true });
    List.Add(new AvailableRoomModel { Id = 2, RoomNumber = "102", Occupied = true });
    List.Add(new AvailableRoomModel { Id = 3, RoomNumber = "103", Occupied = true });
}


public async void GetAvailableRooms()
{
    try
    {
        AvailableRooms = await _getAvailableRoomsService.getRooms();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //TODO   
    }

}
```

Have tested that if I bind my ItemsControl to the list with name = List it works (its fast enough) but it dosen't work when binding to AvailableRooms.

I really don't want a searchCommand in the view I can click, Just want to have the list populated before showing the view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `async void`. If you would like to await a method then its return type must be `Task` or `Task<T>`.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AvailableRoomModel>> GetAvailableRooms()
{
    try
    {
        return await _getAvailableRoomsService.getRooms();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //TODO   
    }
}
```

In the ctor you cannot await this method, so you can simply call this method like this:

```
public RoomsViewModel(IGetAvailableRoomsService getAvailableRoomsService)
{
    //Injection
    _getAvailableRoomsService = getAvailableRoomsService;

    //Get all rooms
    AvailableRooms =
        new ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel>(
            GetAvailableRooms().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        );

    // ...
}
```

UPDATE:

You should also implement `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your viewmodel and you have to use full properties to be able to raise the `PropertyChanged` event. The `ObservableCollection<T>` itself implements this interface but setting a property will not raise this event unless we raise it.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class RoomsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /* constructor goes here from previous code block */

    private ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel> availableRooms;
    public ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel> AvailableRooms
    {
        get { return availableRooms; }
        set { availableRooms = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel> list;
    public ObservableCollection<AvailableRoomModel> List
    {
        get { return list; }
        set { list = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: For some reason , it hangs all the time. I have debugged and check that the list get filled, and it does.

Comment: To avoid hanging load the rooms not in the constructor but a separate method inside the viewmodel and call it from an event handler (e.g. `Window.Loaded`) where you can use `async void` for the event handler and in it you can use `await ViewModel.LoadAvailableRooms();`